# Setting a boolean condition depending on a parameter

Tags: java, while-loop, enums, boolean, conditional-statements

I have a while loop inside of a function, like so:

```
private void search() {

    while (!atEnemy()) {
        ...
    }
}
```

However I would now like to use this same function for another purpose, I would like the function:

```
private void search() {

    while (atEnemy()) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Instead of writing a whole new function for this, is there a way to set the clause in the while loop, depending on a parameter (I could pass an enum as a parameter to the `search()` function)? Something like:

```
private void search(Enum true) {
    Condition c = !atEnemy() if true == Enum.true else atEnemy();
    while (!atEnemy()) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not add an argument to your method?

```
private void search(boolean cond) {
    while (atEnemy() == cond) {
        ...
    }
}
```